# login failed for user mytestuser

Tags: sql-server

I have created a login in SQL Server for a user called `mytestuser`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I try to login I get an error as follows:

[image]

I don't know how to fix it. How can I get this user to login as expected?

Comment: The checkbox is ticked that says "user must change password at next login" and This indicates that the password is incorrect. Error: 18456 if that is any help.

Comment: Uncheck enforce password policy/expiration and User must change password...

Comment: unfortunately i had the same issue

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem before.
You probably have to uncheck the "Enforce password policy"
[image: enforce password policy]

Comment: i just unchecked it but still same

Comment: I just re-read your error message and found that you are unable to connect to the database.
Please follow the steps in this link (https://appuals.com/sql-server-error-18456/)

Comment: I followed all the instructions in the document but it still didn't work. i will try Restoro Repair Tool. 
Thanks for your help